# SFCC (demandware) Debugging

Tags: debugging, salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, demandware

How I can debug Controllers or template in SFCC (Demandware) without Eclipse?

I know about atom debugger, but maybe you now something else, something more comfortable.

Answer (score 6):

Please check [VSC code editor](https://www.google.co.jp/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjHwOjPz-zWAhWBopQKHZ5ABywQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcode.visualstudio.com%2F&usg=AOvVaw15O90sm1ios8AUpw56hCml) and [prophet debugger plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SqrTT.prophet). This is an alternative solution for SFCC development against to Eclipse IDE.

Also, you can check this post on [xChange](https://xchange.demandware.com/message/73303#73303)

Answer (score 0):

As from now you can also use Jetbrains IDE with this plugin [Salesforce B2C Commerce ​(SFCC)​](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13668-salesforce-b2c-commerce-sfcc-) to debug your code(and even much more).

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with Package [Prophet Debugger](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SqrTT.prophet) it is Free

Or use Jetbrains IDE with the plugin [Salesforce B2C Commerce ​(SFCC)​](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13668-salesforce-b2c-commerce-sfcc-) it is not free you must buy